# Sympy: simplification of elementary expression fails

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I don't understand why the expression `a * (... + 1) - a` is not being removed while simplification. The example below shows the bug:

```
import sympy as sy

a,b,c = sy.symbols('a b c')
expr = a * (b - c + 1) - a  + (b - c) * (a - b)
print expr              #  printed: a*(b - c + 1) - a + (a - b)*(b - c)
print expr.simplify()   #  printed: a*(b - c + 1) - a + (a - b)*(b - c)
```

On the other side, if I change the expression by

```
expr = a * (b - c + 1) - a
```

and call `simplify()`, I will obtain the expected result `a * (b - c)`.

Sympy version is 1.1rc1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simplify` usually can only do a limited amount of magic. It could be arguably more in this case, but if you want that, you need to make a feature request. In any case it’s better to tell SymPy what specific kind of modifications you want to make.

Here, the following will probably satisfy you:

```
print(expr.factor()) # (2*a - b)*(b - c)
```